# Excel VBA - Drop down with only names

Tags: excel-2010

I have a drop down with 120 names. I have been trying to run a macro  where everytime when I select a name, I need to copy/past in another cell, and keep the names selected in sequence in the same cell. It could be about 20-50 names in this cell 
i.e. Mary, John, Joel, Paul, Cinthia, Michael,

Is there a way to create a macro to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a code to update cell value in the dropdown box's change event.
e.g.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column).Value = ComboBox1.Value
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1).Select

End Sub
```